# Exact line number for C error?

Tags: c

I have a compiled version of the game 'Rogue', as well as its source code. Sometimes, at seemingly random times, the game will put up a non-descriptive error message.

Is there a way of compiling the source in an IDE, and getting the specific line number where the program fails when it is run in the IDE?

Comment: As you have the source, if it is built with a "source database" then there will be ways to debug the source of the error. We would need to know more info, e.g. what platform you are running on, what compiler is building and what tools you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit the error messages to:

```
printf (stderr, "Blah error at %s (%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

you can get the exact location.

Since editing all the messages would be a big pain, I'd suggest you define a macro that does it:

```
#define MYERR(...) do { \
    printf ("@ %s (%d): ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    printf (__VA_ARGS__); \
} while (0)
```

Replace all error messages calls to invoke this macro (thats much easier than appending to each message).

Comment: Note that the line number can be redefined with the #line preprocessor directive, so "exact location" is not always correct.